# Session is getting timed out while HTTP session is share in weblogic

Tags: java, session, weblogic

I have an EAR file which consists of multiple WebApps. I need to share the same HTTP session on each web apps. To achieve this I have set the below three parameters in  **weblogic-application.xml** file.

`<wls:persistent-store-type>memory</wls:persistent-store-type>`

`<wls:sharing-enabled>true</wls:sharing-enabled>`

`<wls:timeout-secs>180</wls:timeout-secs>`

But after these parameters are set whenever I am loging into the system and navigating into other web app the HTTP session is getting timed out immediately and the logout page comes up on the screen.

Any kind of advice will be helpful in this context to share the session and prevent the application to logout automatically. I am stuck with this issue and not able to carry forward further with my changes due to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Enable debug for http from WLS admin console, trace the sessionid and see whats happening.
Paste the relevant output here so I can take a look and comment on it.

Comment: I debuged the application. We have same servlet filter for all of the Webapps. Inside the filter we take the session from the request using the code,  HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); But whenever I am moving to some other Webapp, the session is not coming in the request.